# a regex to parse BEM class selector with javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

here my problem :

I want to split a string into an array of object. 
My string is a BEM class selector like so :

where my string (without dot) would be splitted by matching '__' and '--'.

`foo-bar--baz__foo--bar` = `['foo-bar', '--baz', '__foo', '--bar']`

`foo-bar--baz` = `['foo-bar', '--baz']`

`foo-bar__bar--baz` = `['foo-bar', '__bar', '--baz']`

`foo` = `['foo']`

I tried with the following regex :

```
const regex = /([a-zA-Z0-9']+)(--[a-zA-Z0-9']+)(__[a-zA-Z0-9']+)/g;

while (match = reg.exec(string)) {
    var group1 = match[1];
    var group2 = match[2];
    var group3 = match[3];

    console.log(group1+'; '+group2+'; '+group3);
}
```

but `foo-bar--baz__foo--bar` only output:

```
foo-bar --baz __foo
```

and not the last `--bar`…

I cannot figure out why.

Also, maybe a better overall solution exist to solve my problem…

Thank's for the help

Comment: Are you sure that `foo-bar--baz__foo--bar` is a "valid" BEM identifier?

Comment: @evolutionxbox yes that's a valid BEM class in a variety of BEM flavors.

Comment: @zzzzBov It's just odd. That selector seems to be a BMBEM.

Comment: @evolutionxbox it's just an exemple, but I would not recommend it

Comment: @evolutionxbox, the name BEM is not meant to prescribe the order or quantity of the components. Otherwise most classes would just be `B`, `BM`, or `BE`.

Comment: @zzzzBov true, but what's the logic behind the example? To follow BEM it should be `.foo-bar--baz.__foo-bar__foo--bar` (note that it's two classes, not one).

Comment: @evolutionxbox, never saw that flavor… what's this `.__` prefix ? not in the original spec. Look a bit like SUIT, but with kebab case… it's a first to me.

Comment: @GaelBoyenval that was a typo ;)

Comment: @evolutionxbox, that entirely depends on which variant of BEM you're using. It existed as a high-level set of guidelines before it was [standardized](https://en.bem.info/), so there are a lot of competing structures that can be used.

Comment: @zzzzBov true. A standard must be used if the OP wishes to parse the selectors.

Comment: @evolutionxbox, in fact I'm building a stylelint plugin that can check any variant of BEM, by using a configuration object. So the ultimate goal is to be able to Lint any custom flavor of BEM, among any standard you wish.
I shouldn't have talked about BEM, since nobody is proposing any solution, but prefer to argue about standards… My bad 

Comment: @GaelBoyenval sorry for arguing. It's just very difficult to parse unknown "flavours" of BEM, which is why there's a standard.

Comment: @evolutionxbox, has I said, this is my fault. The problem was badly expressed in the first place. Thank's all for your time anyway. In fact I just want to split a string into chunks by matching set of chars, without removing them from the result. I am now trying in a much less elegant way using indexOf and substring.

Answer (score 1):

try this : `([a-zA-Z0-9^]+[-]?[a-zA-Z0-9^]+)(?:--|__)([a-zA-Z0-9^]+[-]?[a-zA-Z0-9^]+)`

https://regex101.com/r/Xz7MWQ/1

Comment: doesn't this look a bit better? `([a-z0-9]+(-{1})?[a-z0-9]+)|(--|__)`

[regex101.com/r/ov2nMR/2](https://regex101.com/r/ov2nMR/2)

Comment: This doesn't work with `.a`, `.a_b--c` and `.a-bcd`. It should allow single letters in B, E, and M.

Comment: I have noticed visiting the link, that you were answering the question and providing regex for non-BEM selectors, sorry!

Answer (score 1):

```
^([a-z][a-z0-9]*)((__|_|-|--)[a-z0-9]+)*$
```

I passed it to stylelint-config and everything is OK

Comment: It doesn't flag `.a_b_c` as invalid BEM (and it is indeed invalid). Still this regex is closer to being perfect than Jimbot's answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing about BEM but splitting a string into an object is easy.  I have no idea if it's valid BEM.  It won't work with more items in the string.

```js
var a = "foo-bar--baz__foo--bar"
var names = ["block","modifier","element","modifier"];
var arr = a.split(/--|__/g).map(function (el, i) {
  var obj = {};
  obj[names[i]] = el;
  return obj;
});
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: thank's but this work only with the exemple selector, if I have an element at the last position, your code will still use a 'modifier' key.

Comment: @GaelBoyenval you might need to be more strict with your "many flavours" naming.

Answer (score 0):

To parse BEM class selector you may use https://github.com/bem-sdk-archive/bem-naming but `foo-bar--baz__foo--bar` doesn't seem to be a BEM selector ;)

Comment: yes not a good one at least, but it's just an exemple ;). there is many flavor of BEM.

Comment: bem-naming was designed to support different flavors but it's still can't help with this particular naming scheme :)

Comment: arrrrrg, I don't care very much this is not my point… it could be wrong or not, I just want to split it…

Comment: I misread your comment, I thought you were arguing about the validity of the selector. :)